# I cant use long function in python

Tags: python-3.5, numerical-methods

there I want to ask why I cant use `long()` function in python3.6.5? its say `long is not defined`
and what should the function should I use? please anybody help me

Comment: can you show want you want to do ? and how you are doing it ?

Comment: Are you mixing languages and referring to `format long` from matlab? Please add a code fragment where you would like to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

there is no long integer in Python 3, you should just be able to use int()?

Comment: but i want to use more decimal number, for example i want to calculate this 1 / 3 * 50 + 50 + 100 and its just show 166 but i want to get 166.666666666666 so how i solve it?

Comment: did i have to use float function?

Comment: No need to use anything the default value is a float. You can round whenever you want using `round()`